# Changing value of PointerArray

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, input

I am trying to change a value in a array.
But i can't figure out how to do it without getting weird output.

```
char *wordsArray[9] = {"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5","word6","word7","word8","word9"};

int *temp;
temp = &wordsArray[randNumber1];

wordsArray[randNumber1] = wordsArray[randNumber2]; //this works
wordsArray[randNumber2] = temp;                    //this does not
```

I am not familair with pointers so at this moment i dont know what i am doing wrong
All help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: But i can't figure out how to do it without getting weird output? What do you mean by "weird"?

Comment: like this: Ƈ����Ͽ̇Շ݇������

Comment: Those are nothing but garbage values. Implemented the solutions given below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 4 has the biggest problem. There should be a compiler warning being issued there. Normally something like incompatible pointer.

```
char *wordsArray[9] = {"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5","word6","word7","word8","word9"};

char *temp; // your array contains char pointers, not integers
temp = wordsArray[randNumber1]; // no need to take the address, you get the array element

wordsArray[randNumber1] = wordsArray[randNumber2];
wordsArray[randNumber2] = temp;                    // now this will work
```

As a learning exercise: try to forget about pointers:

```
typedef char * my_string_type;

my_string_type wordsArray[9] = {"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5","word6","word7","word8","word9"};

my_string_type temp = wordsArray[randNumber1];
wordsArray[randNumber1] = wordsArray[randNumber2];
wordsArray[randNumber2] = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

`int *temp;` should be `char* temp`

You are trying to store `int` in `char` Array.

Answer (score 0):

int *temp;

means that temp is an int*. Moreover int* temp; is the same as int *temp; You can think that temp is an int* i.e. a pointer to int and *temp is an int.

If you want to reproduce the

```
wordsArray[randNumber1] = wordsArray[randNumber2];
```

behavior by using temp:

```
temp = &wordsArray[randNumber3];
```

Keep in mind that wordsArray[randNumber3] is an int and &wordsArray[randNumber3] is a pointer to int. *temp is an int. Thus
you have to type

```
wordsArray[randNumber2] = *temp;
```

Think of * and & as one the inverse of the other and you are doing something like this:

```
wordsArray[randNumber1] = *&wordsArray[randNumber3];
```

Convincing enough?